# $f_n\text{ bounded }, f_n\to f\text{ uniformly}$, then $f$ bounded

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

> > Let $(X,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ be a measurable space, $f_n,n\geqslant 1$ measurable and bounded functions with $f_n\to f$ uniformly. Would like to know if then $f$ is measurable and bounded, too.

I think the measurability of $f$ follows from the fact that - if $f_n, n\geqslant 1$ is measurable - then $\lim_n f_n$ is measurable too, if this limit exists. Here it exists, anyway the task sounds like this.

Now I would like to prove that $f$ is bounded, i.e. I have to find a $M\geqslant 0$, so that $\lvert f(x)\rvert\leqslant M$ for all $x\in X$. Do not know if my proof is correct.

$$
\lvert f(x)\rvert=\sup_n\lvert f_n(x)\rvert
$$

Comment: First, find $N$ so that $f_N$ is within $1$ of $f$ uniformly.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your sentence "within 1 of $f$ uniformly". What do you mean with that?

Comment: $|f_N(x)-f(x)|<1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Doesn't it follows from :

$$ \Vert f_{n} - f \Vert_{\infty} + \Vert f_{n} \Vert_{\infty} \geq \Vert f \Vert_{\infty} \geq - \Vert f_{n} - f \Vert_{\infty} + \Vert f_{n} \Vert_{\infty} $$ ?

Comment: It might be better to write $|f(x)|\le| f(x)-f_N(x)+f_N(x)|\le \Vert f_N-f\Vert_\infty +\Vert f_N\Vert_\infty$, for all $x$. Then you can say $\Vert f\Vert_\infty<\infty$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Ok.Choose $\varepsilon=1$, then there exists a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that for all $x\in X$ and for $n\geqslant N$ it is $\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert < 1$. So for any $x\in X$ it is $\lvert f(x)\rvert=\lvert f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)\rvert\leqslant 1+\lvert f_n(x)\rvert\leqslant 1+M_n$ for $n$ large enough. Here with $M_n$ I mean the boundary of $f_n$. Right?

Comment: Yes. But, you want to fix an $n$. May as well just use $N$.

Comment: Ok, thank you for helping!